# moment().toDate() language

Tags: javascript, momentjs, locale

i'm spending to much time on this.

I'm tryng to get the momento().toDate() in pt format, no falling to succeed.

Already add to may react code

```
import 'moment/locale/pt';
import moment from 'moment';

moment.locale('pt');

console.log(moment(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').toDate());
```

But my result is something like this **Wed Feb 26 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000** and not **Qua Fev 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would recommend you to stop using Moment.js as you its not actively being maintained. Consider [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/). Consider this [link](https://day.js.org/docs/en/i18n/changing-locale) for locale changes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) `toDate` method returns related JavaScript `Date` object so it does not take into account the locale you've set to moment;

If you want to get a formatted localized date you can do as follows

```js
moment.locale('pt');
moment(new Date()).format('MMMM');
```

Below, you can find an example:

```js
moment.locale('pt');
const result = moment(new Date()).format('MMMM');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
```

However, as @Jibin Bose has mentioned `moment.js` is not actively maintained for now and I'd also proposed you to take a look at other libraries like [`date-fns`](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns) for example.